# css and javascripts not loading in heroku after deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

css and java scripts are not loading in **heroku** , once i run the application i am getting like this in the backend

2015-06-09T13:36:38.985035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-06-09T13:36:41.933838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-06-09T13:36:44.109165+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-09T13:36:46.815199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 56008`
2015-06-09T13:36:52.415454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

i am getting **Stopping all processes with SIGTERM**  **Process exited with status 0** please suggest me how to correct it.

Comment: but here the process exited with status 0 .is that same , i will try it thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

What version of rails are you useing?

Did you add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile ?

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

 gem 'mysql2'
gem 'rake', '=0.9.2.2'
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

Comment: gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'paperclip',"~> 2.3"
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'

gem "authlogic", '3.1.0'
gem "rails3-generators"
gem 'paperclip',"~> 2.3"
gem "ckeditor", "3.7.3"
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'calendar_date_select', :git => 'http://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git'
gem "dynamic_form", "~> 1.1.4"
gem "wicked_pdf", "~> 0.9.4"
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

Comment: gem 'turbolinks'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
gem "private_pub"
gem "faye"

group :production do
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end